# Can't import com.auth0.jwt in Java project

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, jwt, auth0

I'm using the following Maven dependency for the [auth0 jwt library for Java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

When I try to import the package in a Java servlet like this:

```
com.auth0.jwt
```

the `auth0` isn't recognised, and I get the message `Cannot resolve symbole 'auth0'`

I've tried different versions of the dependency, and also cleaning and rebuilding the project, and closing and opening IntelliJ, but it still isn't recognised.

I've also looked at the [auth0 Java quickstart](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/java/01-login#integrate-auth0-in-your-application), which suggests that for a Java servlet I may need to use these Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
  <artifactId>mvc-auth-commons</artifactId>
  <version>1.+</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm already using the 2nd one (for the servlet-api). The com.auth0 dependency isn't recognised at all though, as a valid dependency.

What can I try in order to import `com.auth0.jwt`?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same dependency in a Google Cloud Endpoints project:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I could then import `com.auth.jwt`. I'm guessing that the library only works inside an Endpoints API.